# 2008 Toyota Rav4 passenger turn signal flashing rapidly, hazards normal

Tags: turn-signal, rav4

The passenger turn signal started flashing at twice the speed of the driver's side signal.  Initial research suggests a bulb is dead (or dying).  I changed the front bulb, but the issue still remains.  I then put on the hazards, which both blink at the same, regular speed.  Should I still be changing out bulbs, or is this now something with the flasher relay, or maybe the socket itself?  Anymore troubleshooting I can do?

Thanks

Comment: Are all of the bulbs conventional incandescents? Sometimes people will replace an incandescent lamp with a low-power LED that lacks the resistor to make it draw the same amount of current, so the flasher blinks faster. If any of your lamps are LED's, it's possible that this load resistor failed, but the LED light is still lit.

Comment: If you have LED lights, it could be that one or more of the LEDs is out. Just had this happen on a set of aftermarket LED taillights. If both blinkers are blinking fast, replace the relay.

Comment: They aren't LED lights, everything is stock.  Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 4):

Two things.

First, you can almost guarantee with the blinker going fast one of the bulbs are out. This might include any of the small bulbs which are side markers as well as the main lights which are front/rear. Look around the "good" side of the vehicle with the blinkers on to figure out where the small bulb might be, then look to see if it is flashing on the other side. Easiest way I know of to find the culprit.

Second, the hazard flasher is a separate circuit from the blinkers, so this is why it still flashes the same on both sides during operation. A bulb out will not affect the speed at which it blinks.

Comment: After looking at all the other bulbs, I noticed that the high beams do not turn on at all.  When I try to switch them on, the in dash passenger turn signal indicator lights up, but no high beams.  I replaced the high beams bulbs, but still no luck.  Any thoughts?